# set tab color in a tabbed terminal emulator

Tags: shell, terminal, colors, gnome-terminal, tabs

I would like to set in my terminal emulator (i.e. gnome-terminal) the color of the tabs like in the osx's terminal emulator. Is there this feature in any of the linux terminal emulator plethora?

EDIT: below a picture to better explain the desired result.

[image]

Comment: You might get better results on http://superuser.com/ or http://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What do you mean the color of the tabs? The tabs themselves? The window background? Could you post a screenshot of your desired result?

Comment: @terdon, the result would be like the one shown above

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what OS/X's terminal emulator does with colour on tabs, but if using GNU `screen` in `xterm`, you could add something like:

```
hardstatus string '%D %d %M - %c - %h (%n)^G^[]11;TekHVC:%n10/80/20'
```

To your `~/.screenrc` to have a different background colour in every `screen` window/tab/pane (however you want to call them).

`screen` displays the hard status in the xterm title bar by outputting something like:

```
\e]2;blah\a
```

Above we set blah to include `\a\e]11;TekHVC:%n10/80/20` where `%n` is expanded to the window number so for the first window, it becomes:

```
\e]2;...\a\e]11;TekHVC:010/80/20\a
```

`\e]11;...\a` is the xterm escape sequence to set the background colour. It supports various colour specifications, those supported by `XParseColor` from the X libraries. The `TekHVC:Hue/Value/Chroma` one, where `Hue` takes values from 0 to 360 (and wraps) allows us to select a different colour for each window (10, 110, 210, 310, 410 (aka 50), 150, 250...)